# Laravel display SEO tag automatically through Route name

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I have question about Laravel.

I want display SEO tag automatically from Database but I do not know how to do.

I have route like this

```
Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'SeoController@index',
    'as' => 'homepage'
]);
Route::get('/about', [
    'uses' => 'SeoController@index',
    'as' => 'about'
]);
```

From `SeoController` I want to display view base on `Route` url;

```
public function index()
    {
        switch ($route) {
            case '/':
                $title = "Homepage";
                return view('welcome', ['title'=> $title]); 
                break;
            case '/about':
                $title = "About page";
                return view('about', ['title'=> $title]);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

How can I check $route to know which route come?

Thank you so much

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#accessing-the-current-route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would love to suggest a better way of doing this in Laravel.

In Laravel, you would want to define different controller methods for each pages and return a view like so:

```
class SeoController extends Controller
{
    public function home()
    {
        return view('home');
    }

     public function about()
    {
        return view('about');
    }

    public function contact()
    {
        return view('contact');
    }
}
```

Ensure you have the routes registered in `web.php` as:

```
Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'SeoController@home',
    'as' => 'homepage'
]);

Route::get('/about', [
    'uses' => 'SeoController@about',
    'as' => 'about'
]);

Route::get('/contact', [
    'uses' => 'SeoController@contact',
    'as' => 'contact'
]);
```

And also ensure you have the corresponding blade file for each of these views in the view folder.